# Preventing posts from origin other than domain with axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm working on my first website, and am using axios to send post/get requests to the backend.  I'm using React on the front-end and node/express on the back-end.  I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent posts from a source other than my site.

For example, if I make this exact request through postman I am still be able to post comments, meaning that someone could post with names and ID's other than themselves.

Here is a typical post request made on the front-end:

```
axios.post('/api/forumActions/postComment', {}, {
            params: {
              postUserID: this.props.auth.user.id,
              name: `${this.props.auth.user.firstName} ${this.props.auth.user.lastName}`,
              commentContent: this.state.commentContent,
              respondingToPost: this.state.postID,
              respondingToComment: this.state.postID
            }
          })
```

And here is how it gets processed on the back-end

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
require("./config/passport")(passport);

app.post('/postComment', (req, res)=>{
    var commentData={
        postUserID: req.query.postUserID,
        name: req.query.name,
        commentContent: req.query.commentContent,
        respondingToPost: req.query.respondingToPost,
        respondingToComment: req.query,respondingToComment
    }

    //Write commentData to database
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port} !`));
```

I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to ramp up security to prevent post requests being made from anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to accomplish this. [This](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) is a pretty good guide on how to configure it, specifically [this section](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors).  You can configure it for certain routes, or all across the board.

CORS sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, which you can [read more about here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) - it only allows requests from specified origins.

Keep in mind you don't need that package to accomplish this.. you could always build your own middleware for this.

Something like:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://yourdomain.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Within the Express documentation, they provide the following demo code, which you should be able to use as a helper.

- [Client](https://github.com/TroyGoode/node-cors-client)
- [Server](https://github.com/TroyGoode/node-cors-server)

---

You could use a makeshift middleware with special headers.. but then all someone has to do is read your client side source code, or look at the network tab in their browser to figure out which headers you're sending, so then can duplicate them. It would prevent random people from snooping, though..

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Custom special middleware..
function blockBadHosts({ host, whitelistHeader, whitelistHeaderValue }) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if(req.headers['host'] === host) {
            if(whitelistHeader && req.headers[whitelistHeader] === whitelistHeaderValue) {
                next();
            } else {
                res.status(301).send('BAD REQUEST');
            }
        } else {
            res.status(301).send("BAD REQUEST");
        }
    }
}

// Options for our custom middleware
const badHostOptions = { 
    host: "localhost:3000",
    whitelistHeader: "x-my-special-header", // Request must contain this header..
    whitelistHeaderValue: "zoo"             // .. with this value
}

// This should succeed
app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("from /success");
});

// This should fail even if sent from Postman without correct headers
app.get('/failure', blockBadHosts(badHostOptions), (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("from /failure");
});

// 404 route
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send("Uh oh can't find that");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port: '${port}'`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Still having trouble, I'm still able to make a get request I set up on the back end from Postman.  This is how I set it up on the server side...  
`app.use(cors({
  origin: 'xyz.com'
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "xyz.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/testing', function (req, res, next) {res.json("Get request success")})
app.listen(80, () => console.log("Server running on port 80"));`
Something more I need to do?

Comment: Got it - apologies and thank you for the response.  So in order to filter out post/get requests from sources OTHER than my webpage I'll need to initiate some sort of authentication between server and client?  Is there any good documentation on how to do this with react and node?  Thanks again sir.

Comment: So the reason it doesn't work with Postman is because it's not a browser and doesn't care about cors... Browsers will respect the CORS header, though. [Here](https://node-cors-client.netlify.com/) is a good example (if you open your dev tools you can see requests being sent to a different url than the origin). [Front end](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors-client) code for that demo, and [back end](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors-server) code.

Comment: Lets say you have a website that hosts pictures.. and you don't want other websites using them.. You could use CORS to prevent someguyswebsite.com from accessing your assets.. but it sounds like you want something different than that.. I have updated my answer with some makeshift middleware that checks headers, but ultimately it sounds like you are wanting authentication tokens. Thats really the only way you can be "for sure" a trusted person is sending requests to you. [More on JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

Comment: The more I think about it the more I think configuring CORS is what you're looking for.. check out that example.. You can configure it so if someone sends an AJAX request (via a browser) to your site, while they're at, lets say, yahoo.com, it would fail.  They could still use something like Postman, though.. since browsers are what assist in CORS.